# Validating JSON file with JSON schema in Emacs using flymake/flycheck?

Tags: json, emacs, schema, flymake

Is it possible to validate JSON file using JSON schema in Emacs with flymake/flycheck?
What would be the best validator to detect schema-related error and notify it to Emacs
with appropriate error message and location?

Comment: Flycheck does not include a syntax checker for schema-based JSON validation.  You need to write your own…

Comment: Maybe https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint or do you need more elaborate schema options?

Answer (score 2):

Theres is [flymake-json](https://github.com/purcell/flymake-json), which uses [jsonlint](https://github.com/zaach/jsonlint). It can be installed with `package-install`.

Comment: Not available in Emacs 26.3

Answer (score 1):

Flycheck has support for JSON: https://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/languages.html#json
Also lsp-mode can be used with either flymake or flycheck: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-json/